# Why does Babel throw Unknown option: ... Children?

Tags: babeljs, babel-jest, circleci-2.0

Trying to run build on CircleCi and it's failing on test. Same stuff is working perfect on my local.
My .babelrc config:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    ["babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend", {
      "globals": ["Error", "Array"]
    }],
    ["transform-runtime", {
      "polyfill": false,
      "regenerator": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

Error I'm getting from circleCI:

```
yarn test v0.27.5
$ jest 
 FAIL  src/utils/service-helper.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: [BABEL] /home/circleci/repo/src/utils/service-helper.test.js: Unknown option: /home/circleci/repo/node_modules/react/index.js.Children. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more information about options.

    A common cause of this error is the presence of a configuration options object without the corresponding preset name. Example:

    Invalid:
      `{ presets: [{option: value}] }`
    Valid:
      `{ presets: [['presetName', {option: value}]] }`
```

Any idea what is going on as the same configuration is working on another project

Answer (score 5):

The error is unhelpful, but the issue is that your config has `react` in the preset list, but it can't find the `babel-preset-react` module in your `node_modules`, so instead it is loading the `react` module itself as if it were a preset. But since the `"react"` module *isn't* a preset, Babel throws.

Most likely, you've forgotten to list `babel-preset-react` in your `package.json`.